# Have Visual Studio output window color messages according to log level?

Tags: visual-studio, serilog

When running an app in Visual Studio I love having colored messages in the console window.  But is it possible to have colors showing in the Output window as well?  Right now it's all monochrome.

Answer (score 6):

Try this extension. I used it for VS 2022 and works really good. You can even configure which color you want to see.

> [link for VS2022 marketplace - VSColorOutput64](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MikeWard-AnnArbor.VSColorOutput64)

[image]

[image]

> [Link for another extension - Output enhancer](https://%3E%20https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NikolayBalakin.Outputenhancer)

[image]

[image]